# Get bar code value from c# for SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, barcodes

We have a SharePoint list with bar codes enabled. We also have a Xamarin App that need to scan printed bar codes and then find values in the SharePoint list that matches the value. But how do you get the value from a given scanned bar code in a Xamarin app that matches the standard SharePoint Online uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint generates a classic [Code 128 Barcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#:%7E:text=Code%20128%20is%20a%20high,%2FIEC%208859%2D1..)

Modern list example
[image]

The same SharePoint barcode when we click on it:

[image]

To read the **Code 128** in Xamarin, use any of the C# Barcode reading library. For example, [ZXing](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net)

Small example decoding a barcode inside a bitmap (.Net 2.0/3.5/4.x). [Source](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net)

```
// create a barcode reader instance
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
// load a bitmap
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.LoadFrom("C:\\sample-barcode-image.png");
// detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
// do something with the result
if (result != null)
{
   txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
   txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks appreciated!